# Print out names from Mapped information

Tags: java

I've created a Map with ten people's details, I want to then print out the names. 
At the moment I have to print out each one individually, I want to have about 200 people so I wanted to know if it would be possible to print the names out in a loop.

(simplified code)

```
public class PersonDetails implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    ...

    public PersonDetails(int Age, String Name) {

        name = Name;
        age = Age;
        ...
    }
}




public class Test implements Serializable {

   Map<String, PersonDetails> people = new TreeMap<String, PersonDetails>();

public Test() {

        //10 people added
        for(int x = 0; x<10; x++){
            addPerson();
        }

        PersonDetails p0 = people.get("0");
        String p0name = p0.getName();
        System.out.println(p0name);

        PersonDetails p1 = people.get("1");
        String p1name = p1.getName();
        System.out.println(p1name);

        PersonDetails p2 = people.get("2");
        String p2name = p2.getName();
        System.out.println(p2name);

        PersonDetails p3 = people.get("3");
        String p3name = p3.getName();
        System.out.println(p3name);
        ...
        (I would like to loop this)
}
```

OUTPUT: 
Connor
Phil
Nick
Mike
Sarah
Tom
Jenny
Eric
Jerry
Dave

Is it possible to have the same output and loop these outputs? I have tried an ArrayLists but I can't get it to work with this problem, and I am not sure if it is possible.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for sorting that out for me Bakudan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is:

```
for (PersonDetails p: people.keySet())
{
    System.out.println(p.getName());
}
```

You should specify the types of the `people` member variable when declaring and initializing. I think the key is a `String`, given `get("0")`, so:

```
Map<String, PersonDetails> people = new TreeMap<String, PersonDetails>();
```

To use an `ArrayList`:

```
List<PersonDetails> people = new ArrayList<PersonDetails>();

people.add(new PersonDetails(42, "Martin"));

for (PersonDetails p: people)
{
    System.out.println(p.getName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much both these answers are so helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, PersonDetails> people = new HashMap<String, PersonDetails>();
// add to the Map this way
people.put(person.getName(), person);
for (Person p : people.keySet()) {
    System.out.print(String.format("%s ", p.getName());
}
System.out.println();
```

You get the idea.

Comment: Thanks you so much both these answers are so helpful